# GetThumbnailAsync() takes too long in Local Storage

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I was creating a Windows phone 8.1 (RT) app where I'm  having a few images both in the LocalStorage and also in the Pictures Library where I'm loading the images using GetThumbnailAsync().
For a PNG image of size 6MB+ the GetThumbnailAsync() in PicturesLibrary takes a few msec while the same image when copied to LocalStorage in the App takes around 10 secs to get the thumbnail.

Also I used

`getThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.ListView,100,ThumbnailOptions.ResizeThumbnail)`

Yet it takes a long time but returns the Thumbnail in the desired pixel size. Can anyone point out why it takes so much time in case of LocalStorage and if there are any alternatives to make it fast.

Comment: Check where LocalStorage and PicturesLibrary are located (check the file's path). SD card may be slower than phone's memory.

Comment: @Romasz : Both the images are located in SD card

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system pre-caches thumbnails for images in the pictures library, whereas it can't do that for images in an app's isolated storage.

There are two workarounds here:

1. Move the picture to a public location where the system can pre-generate a thumbnail
2. Embed a thumbnail in the EXIF data for the image in your local storage. Then the system can do a fast extract and return a thumbnail more quickly. Currently it has to decode the entire 6+ MB file to generate a thumbnail, where a fast extract only needs to pop open the much smaller thumbnail

Comment: What happens to a file if the EXIF data is missing? Do you think I could create a custom cache which stores the thumbnails?

Comment: If the EXIF data is missing, the system is going to decode the entire file and generate a thumbnail. It will then will, if space permits on the device, cache the results for a later call. You really don't want to rely on the caching in the system store though because on the lower end phones (and a lot of the high end ones) there is rarely enough space for us to be caching thumbnails from the app isolated storage

Comment: If you are going to create your own cache, then I would recommend either just displaying the thumbnails from there (and completely sidestepping the system call) or sticking the results in the photo file. I'd recommend a quick perf test to see what is faster before diving in to the code too far